# Python & Matplotlib: put x-axis in centre but tick and label is not followed to the x-axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

In `Matplotlib`, I want to put x-axis always go through (0, 0). Followed is a small code. As you can see, x-axis is adjusted to the middle of figure. What I want is x-axis shown at (0, 1.5) always at (0,0).

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

x=[0,2.7,5.4]
y=[0,3.0,0]
ax.plot(x, y)

ax.spines['bottom'].set_position('center')
ax.spines['right'].set_color('none')
ax.spines['top'].set_color('none')
#  ax.spines['bottom'].set_color('none')

plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: If you want the x-axis to pass through (0,0), why do you have `ax.spines['bottom'].set_position('center')`?

Comment: @BigBen If I commented the line you mentioned, the x-axis is at the bottom, roughly at (0, 3.2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](https://matplotlib.org/api/spines_api.html#matplotlib.spines.Spine.set_position), use `'zero'` when setting the position of the spine:

```
ax.spines['bottom'].set_position('zero')
```

Output:

[image]